# The BOOM of social media, related with new features of self-promotion, rather than chats to engage with others?

Tags: social-psychology, evolution

I was involved in a group project were we were connecting people with a PenPal, by receiving their stories. Unfortunately, people were being driven away because of PenPal idea. We changed the project and we were met with an increase number of submission, now people only have to share their own story, the PenPal was removed.
Is there any studies that can help me interpret this reaction, since the project ways also aimed to people between 16-25 years old. Are they more likely to be more interested in self-promoting, than engaging in conversation with others.